# Error 404 in stackexchange webmasters "about us" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, tour

There is the `About us` link in https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ that redirect to this page https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/company/about but the page return error 404.

Apparently the same happens in this website's footer "about us" link too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in the right place, thanks for reporting it.

We recently moved our "about us" pages from `stackexchange.com/about` to `stackoverflow.com/company/about` so the relative link is probably causing this issue. Fixing now.

EDIT: Confirmed fix.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, to ruin your party, but this bug is much wider than just the WM site.

A list of locations that go wrong:

- The `about us` in every site, excluding stackexchange.com and Stack Overflow;
- The `work here` in every site, excluding stackexchange.com and Stack Overflow;
- All meta sites are broken too, including Stack Overflow.

Stack Apps and Area51 are okay, so is mobile since it doesn't have those links there.

This seems related to a change in the company name and a move to Stack Overflow as the 'main' domain name.

I think ever site should redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/company/about and https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here as they seem to be the correct ones.

Comment: Noted. Looks like we're just dealing with bad relative links here.

Comment: No problem. I am checking all other special sites now. Stack Apps seems to be broken too. Mobile is okay since it doesn't use the links there.

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: Confirmed that.